# Inserting foreign key data using Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm having an issue composing a chained insert query using slick. I want to insert a row, have the primary key returned, then insert a new row with a foreign key to the row I just inserted.

I've tried using flatmap to chain the result of the first insert into the second insert, however the following code seems to only perform the first insert into the "users" table, and not the second insert into "lists"

Sample code is below, thank you in advance for the help!

```
package com.example.jdbc

import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object DatabaseControllerMin {

  lazy val db = Database.forConfig("postgres")

  lazy val recreateTables = DBIO.seq(
    // drop the old tables
    (users.schema ++ lists.schema).drop,
    // Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys
    (users.schema ++ lists.schema).create
  )

  class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "users") {

    def id = column[Int]("user_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def * = (id, name)
  }

  lazy val users = TableQuery[Users]

  class Lists(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, Int)](tag, "lists") {

    def id = column[Int]("list_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def userId = column[Int]("user_id")

    def * = (id, name, userId)

    def user = foreignKey("users", userId, users)(_.id)
  }

  lazy val lists = TableQuery[Lists]

  def recreateDatabase = {
    try {
      val q = recreateTables andThen {
        users returning users.map(_.id) into ((user, id) => user.copy(_1 = id)) +=(0, "Tyler")
      }  flatMap {
        user => {
          lists +=(0, s"${user._2}'s List", user._1)
        }
      }
      db.run(q)
    } finally db.close
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    recreateDatabase onComplete {
      case Success(x) => {
        println("Success!!!")
      }
      case Failure(t) => {
        println("Failure")
        t.printStackTrace
      }
    }
  }
}
```